# JavaScript calculator input not clearing and decimal allowed multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
let display = document.getElementById('display');
let output,
  zero,
  decimal;

// Loop through all buttons to output value to display div
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    output = display.innerHTML += e.target.value;

    if (output.length > 16) {
      alert('Maximum input reached');
    }
  });
};

// Delete button functionality
document.getElementById('buttonDelete').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === 'delete') {
    display.innerHTML = '';
  }
});



document.querySelector('#buttonZero').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  zero = e.target.value;

  if (display.innerHTML === '') {
    output = display.innerHTML = zero;
  } else if (display.innerHTML === output) {
    output = display.innerHTML += zero;
  }
});

document.querySelector('#buttonDecimal').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  decimal = e.target.value;
  if (display.innerHTML === '') {
    output = display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('0.');
  } else if (display.innerHTML === output) {
    display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('.');
  }
});


document.querySelector('#buttonEqual').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (display.innerHTML === output) {
    display.innerHTML = eval(output);
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = '';
  }
});

let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
  operators[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    operator = e.target.value;

    if (display.innerHTML === '') {
      display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('');
    } else if (output) {
      display.innerHTML = output.concat(operator);
    }

  });
}
```

```css
#calculatorBody {
   background-color: skyblue;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.calculatorButton {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #595959;
   padding: 25px;
   margin: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   color: #fff;
}

.calculatorButton:active{
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #000;
}

#buttonZero {
   width: 138px;
}

#buttonDelete {
   width: 132px;
   background-color: #ff3333;
}

#buttonEqual {
   background-color: #33cc33;
   color: #000;
}

#buttonPeriod {
   background-color: #404040;
}

.number {
   background-color: #404040;
}

.operator {
   background-color: #a6a6a6;
}



#display {
   font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: solid gray 2px;
   background-color: #d9d9d9;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   width: 80%;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
   font-size: 21px;
   padding-top: 12px;
   height: 55px;
   padding-right: 4px;
   text-align: right;
}


/*#display p {
   float: right;
   font-size: 35px;
   margin-top: -25px;
}*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
   .calculatorButton {
      padding: 20px;
   }
   #display {
      margin-top: 20px;
   }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="calculatorBody" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div id="display"></div>
          </div>
            <div id="buttonSection">
              <div class="row">
                <button value="delete" id="buttonDelete" class="calculatorButton operator">Delete</button>
                <button value="%" id="buttonPercent" class="calculatorButton operator">%</button>
                <button value="+" id="buttonPlus" class="calculatorButton operator">+</button>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <button value="7" id="button7" class="calculatorButton number">7</button>
                <button value="8" id="button8" class="calculatorButton number">8</button>
                <button value="9" id="button9" class="calculatorButton number">9</button>
                <button value="/" id="buttonDivide" class="calculatorButton operator">/</button>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <button value="4" id="button4" class="calculatorButton number">4</button>
                <button value="5" id="button5" class="calculatorButton number">5</button>
                <button value="6" id="button6" class="calculatorButton number">6</button>
                <button value="*" id="buttonMultiply" class="calculatorButton operator">x</button>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <button value="1" id="button1" class="calculatorButton number">1</button>
                <button value="2" id="button2" class="calculatorButton number">2</button>
                <button value="3" id="button3" class="calculatorButton number">3</button>
                <button value="-" id="buttonMinus" class="calculatorButton operator">-</button>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <button value="0" id="buttonZero" class="calculatorButton zero">0</button>
                <button value="." id="buttonDecimal" class="calculatorButton decimal">.</button>
                <button value="=" id="buttonEqual" class="calculatorButton equal">=</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am working on making a basic JavaScript calculator without using jQuery.

The calculator is functional but the result doesn't clear when the next input is entered and the result just rolls over to the next calculation. I also need the decimal to only be allowed once.

Any help is appreciated also any tips on making the code better would be nice but not necessary. I'm kinda new and really want to improve on my vanilla JavaScript skills.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an actual working example using the code snippet in the editor? It would go a long way to helping us help you.

Comment: Sorry first time posting didn't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, you need to wrap your code in an onload function in order to ensure that your script will only be called after your nodes are ready.
- There are many ways to clear the screen for next calculations. One of which is to use a flag variable, which will be set to true when finishing an operation.
- For the decimal, an alternative way is to use regular expressions to filter out redundant decimals

  /^[+-]?\d+(.\d+)?$/

Or simply, you can use the indexOf function to see if a decimal already exists.
Below, are updated snippets per the suggestions above.

```
<script>

function myFunction(){

     let calculated= false;
     const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
let display = document.getElementById('display');
let output,
  zero,
  decimal;

// Loop through all buttons to output value to display div
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(calculated){
        calculated= false;
        display.innerHTML= "";
    }
    output = display.innerHTML += e.target.value;

    if (output.length > 16) {
      alert('Maximum input reached');
    }
  });
};

// Delete button functionality
document.getElementById('buttonDelete').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === 'delete') {
    display.innerHTML = '';
  }
});



document.querySelector('#buttonZero').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  zero = e.target.value;

  if (display.innerHTML === '') {
    output = display.innerHTML = zero;
  } else if (display.innerHTML === output) {
    output = display.innerHTML += zero;
  }
});

document.querySelector('#buttonDecimal').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  decimal = e.target.value;
  if (display.innerHTML === '') {
    output = display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('0.');
  } else if (display.innerHTML === output && display.innerHTML.indexOf(".") < 0) {
    display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('.');
  }
});


document.querySelector('#buttonEqual').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (display.innerHTML === output) {
    display.innerHTML = eval(output);
    calculated= true;
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = '';
  }
});

let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
  operators[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    operator = e.target.value;

    if (display.innerHTML === '') {
      display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('');
    } else if (output) {
      display.innerHTML = output.concat(operator);
    }

  });
}


     }





    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="calculatorBody"
                class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="display"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="buttonSection">
                        <div class="row">
                            <button value="delete" id="buttonDelete"
                                class="calculatorButton operator">Delete</button>
                            <button value="%" id="buttonPercent"
                                class="calculatorButton operator">%</button>
                            <button value="+" id="buttonPlus"
                                class="calculatorButton operator">+</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button value="7" id="button7" class="calculatorButton number">7</button>
                            <button value="8" id="button8" class="calculatorButton number">8</button>
                            <button value="9" id="button9" class="calculatorButton number">9</button>
                            <button value="/" id="buttonDivide"
                                class="calculatorButton operator">/</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button value="4" id="button4" class="calculatorButton number">4</button>
                            <button value="5" id="button5" class="calculatorButton number">5</button>
                            <button value="6" id="button6" class="calculatorButton number">6</button>
                            <button value="*" id="buttonMultiply"
                                class="calculatorButton operator">x</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button value="1" id="button1" class="calculatorButton number">1</button>
                            <button value="2" id="button2" class="calculatorButton number">2</button>
                            <button value="3" id="button3" class="calculatorButton number">3</button>
                            <button value="-" id="buttonMinus"
                                class="calculatorButton operator">-</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button value="0" id="buttonZero" class="calculatorButton zero">0</button>
                            <button value="." id="buttonDecimal"
                                class="calculatorButton decimal">.</button>
                            <button value="=" id="buttonEqual" class="calculatorButton equal">=</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I'll have to learn more about setting flags. Is wrapping my code in onload function necessary or just good habit?

Comment: It is preferred to avoid getting into unexpected issues. We have to ensure that the main dom nodes are loaded first. When I tried the code for the first time, I got into an issue, which I resolved using the onload way.

Comment: you have two `onload` in your why is that?

Comment: Was a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a flag that will check if the last button clicked was an equal sign, if it was clear the value else concatenate.

```js
 const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
    let display = document.getElementById('display');
    let output,
        zero,
        decimal, equal = false;

    // Loop through all buttons to output value to display div
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {

            if (equal) {
                output = display.innerHTML = e.target.value;
            }else {
                output = display.innerHTML += e.target.value;
            }

            if (output.length > 16) {
                alert('Maximum input reached');
            }
            equal = false;
        });
    };

    // Delete button functionality
    document.getElementById('buttonDelete').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        equal = false;
        if (e.target.value === 'delete'
        ) {
            display.innerHTML = '';
        }
    });


    document.querySelector('#buttonZero').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        equal = false;
        zero = e.target.value;

        if (display.innerHTML === '') {
            output = display.innerHTML = zero;
        } else if (display.innerHTML === output) {
            output = display.innerHTML += zero;
        }
    });

    document.querySelector('#buttonDecimal').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        equal = false;
        decimal = e.target.value;
        if (display.innerHTML === '') {
            output = display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('0.');
        } else if (display.innerHTML === output) {
            display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('.');
        }
    });


    document.querySelector('#buttonEqual').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        equal = true;
        if (display.innerHTML === output) {
            display.innerHTML = eval(output);
        }
        else {
            display.innerHTML = '';
        }
    });

    let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
    for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
        operators[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            equal = false;
            operator = e.target.value;

            if (display.innerHTML === '') {
                display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('');
            } else if (output) {
                display.innerHTML += operator;
            }

        });
    }
```

```css
        #calculatorBody {
            background-color: skyblue;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;

        }

        .calculatorButton {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #595959;
            padding: 25px;
            margin: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .calculatorButton:active {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }

        #buttonZero {
            width: 138px;
        }

        #buttonDelete {
            width: 132px;
            background-color: #ff3333;
        }

        #buttonEqual {
            background-color: #33cc33;
            color: #000;
        }

        #buttonPeriod {
            background-color: #404040;
        }

        .number {
            background-color: #404040;
        }

        .operator {
            background-color: #a6a6a6;
        }

        #display {
            font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: solid gray 2px;
            background-color: #d9d9d9;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            width: 80%;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: block;
            font-size: 21px;
            padding-top: 12px;
            height: 55px;
            padding-right: 4px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        /*#display p {
           float: right;
           font-size: 35px;
           margin-top: -25px;
        }*/

        @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
            .calculatorButton {
                padding: 20px;
            }

            #display {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="calculatorBody" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="display"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="buttonSection">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button value="delete" id="buttonDelete" class="calculatorButton operator">Delete</button>
                        <button value="%" id="buttonPercent" class="calculatorButton operator">%</button>
                        <button value="+" id="buttonPlus" class="calculatorButton operator">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button value="7" id="button7" class="calculatorButton number">7</button>
                        <button value="8" id="button8" class="calculatorButton number">8</button>
                        <button value="9" id="button9" class="calculatorButton number">9</button>
                        <button value="/" id="buttonDivide" class="calculatorButton operator">/</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button value="4" id="button4" class="calculatorButton number">4</button>
                        <button value="5" id="button5" class="calculatorButton number">5</button>
                        <button value="6" id="button6" class="calculatorButton number">6</button>
                        <button value="*" id="buttonMultiply" class="calculatorButton operator">x</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button value="1" id="button1" class="calculatorButton number">1</button>
                        <button value="2" id="button2" class="calculatorButton number">2</button>
                        <button value="3" id="button3" class="calculatorButton number">3</button>
                        <button value="-" id="buttonMinus" class="calculatorButton operator">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button value="0" id="buttonZero" class="calculatorButton zero">0</button>
                        <button value="." id="buttonDecimal" class="calculatorButton decimal">.</button>
                        <button value="=" id="buttonEqual" class="calculatorButton equal">=</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```